# PHP $_POST is outputting '\' when using qoutes

Tags: php, forms, file, post

I have searched Stackoverflow and found a few similar issues but couldn't understand the answers. I only learned PHP 2 days ago so go easy on me please.

My problem is that I am using a form for the user to write and submit some text into a file. When they hit submit the text is written into the file and the next time they visit the form the text remains in the form for them to modify. The problem is that if any form of quotation is entered and submitted then a \ will be added in front of it.

Example: 
user writes: "hello"
User hits submit
The form reloads and "hello" is outputted as \"hello\"

I know that \ cancels out stuff such as quotes so it can be outputted as a string but is it possible to use $_POST to store the form data and not have \ whenever I use a quotation?

Please make your explanations detailed as I am just a novice at PHP. Thanks in advance. Here is the code causing my problems:

```
echo '<div class="wrap">';

// makes an if statement to check if the submit button has been pushed
if ( isset( $_POST['Submit1'] ) ) { 

// opens the include file and writes the contents of "left-form" to the file. left-form is the name of the html text area

$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/options/index_left.php', "w");
fwrite($file,$_POST["left_form"]);
fclose($file);
```

}

```
echo '<p><form method="POST" action=""><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="left_form">';
// includes the contents of the file being written to as the text inside the text field
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/options/index_left.php';
echo '</textarea></p>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit1"></form>';


// sets an if statement to check if the post button has been hit to display a message that it has been posted
if ( isset( $_POST['Submit1'] ) ) {
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["left_form"]) . '</br>HAS BEEN POSTED';
}

echo '</div>';
```

}

Comment: What does `var_dump( get_magic_quotes_gpc() );` output?

Comment: I wrote this at the top of the code and it made no difference but I had int(0) written above the text field.

Comment: Then it's not enabled.

Comment: Oh I see thanks, glad to know it is not magic quotes causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htmlspecial chars will append \ to escape some symbols wrap it in a stripslashes().

```
echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["left_form"])) . '</br>HAS BEEN POSTED';
```

EDIT:

in response to your comment, if the text input is being stored into a database like mysql, try using the mysql_real_escape_string() function and stripslash() around that. otherwise have you tried this without the htmlspecialchars() function?

Comment: Oh yes this seems to have worked (sorry about previous comment saying it wasn't I made an error when implementing the code). Thanks for your help :D. How can I get this to work so that the slashes are stripped out of the text written to the file too?

Comment: What do you mean written to the file? like written to a database?

Comment: If you look at my code under my 2nd code comment that starts: "// opens the include file" you will see that the contents of the text box gets written to a file called "index_left.php". The index_left.php is also used to populate the text area. The 3 lines of code under the comment I just mentions write this into the file. It posts what is stored inside $_POST into the text file. Thanks.

Comment: you might need to keep the htmlspecialchars for that, just when you go to call it for something else, place the stripslashes() around it.

Comment: I think maybe I understand you, so it is not possible write it to the file without the slashes? Presumable this is because it is being stored in the $_POST variable? So I can only call it from the file without the slashes using stripslashes() when I call it? I tried this but it didn't work:  include stripslashes($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/options/index_left.php');

Comment: you can't stripslashes from a file, you need to strip it from the text within the file. it might even be more beneficial to you to change your code around to put the stripslashes function around each entry in the index_left.php file.

Comment: Hmm I tried putting it a few different places but couldn't do it. Sorry but I am a novice and learned PHP 2 days ago and am still learning. I will elaborate what I need the code for. Basically what I am making is a crude form of a CMS in a way, without database access. In my index.php page I have a PHP INCLUDE, which includes the index_left.php into it. Then on the back end of my site I have a textbox, which writes the text into the index_left.php file, when submitted. This in turn updates the index page also (kind of like what a wordpress widget area does). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: just so you know, doing it that way is extremely un-secure. but it may work out by not escaping the special characters for html depending on how you want to call the entry.

Comment: Oh right I didn't know it was un-secure. I am basically making my own wordpress theme to help me learn PHP, so the text entry box is protected by a wordpress login and stuff and the files are in my theme's folder. Is that still un-secure? Should I just be storing the this data in a database instead instead of a .php file in my theme? Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured out the solution now. I didn't understand htmlspecialchars properly but after doing some reading; using it I managed to get stripslashes to work on the include :D. Here is the code, if anyone comes across this post looking for help also: fwrite($file,stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["left_form"])));